# NetBeans: "Package as" uses IDE default platform instead of custom platform

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, platform, netbeans-platform, netbeans-7.3

So I've been messing around with the packaging feature that NetBeans offers, following this tutorial: http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-nbi.html. I didn't like how I had to modify the platform that my IDE was running on in order to customize the installer itself, so I decided to create a copy and just change the platform the application suite was using (Properties->Libraries).

This seemed to work fine, and even packaged that platform as part of the installer. However, when doing the packaging itself, I noticed that it was calling the IDE's platform build script to create the installer rather than the one I had customized. This defeats the purpose, at least in my case, of having the separate platform.

Within the platform manager, under the harness tab, I made sure that the platforms harness was being used rather than the IDE's, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

I verified the behaviour by throwing an echo into both the default IDE platform and my customized platform to see which was being called. I also noticed that the Ant call that gets made at the start of packaging makes an explicit reference to the IDE platform, as well.

I've tried this under 7.2 (currently using 7.3) as 7.3 has had some fairly nasty bugs and thought perhaps it was just recently introduced.

At this point I'm thinking it's a bug, but I was hoping that perhaps someone else had come across this and found some sort of solution or could shed some light on why it's doing what it's doing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is slated to be fixed for 7.4, in case anyone comes across it in the meantime.

Here's a link to the bug ticket: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=229478